# How to include one more argument from a string value in Linq clause?

Tags: vb.net, linq, where-clause

I'd like some help with this Linq, I need to include differents fields in Linq clauses depending of a string value.

The Linq below is fine, I just can't insert "And IIf(genero = "i", vc.modelo_id = 3, vc.sexo = genero) _". Could someone help me?!

```
shirts = _
            From vc In db.VarCamisetas _
            Join m In modelos On vc.modelo_id Equals m.id _
            Join ca In db.Camisetas On vc.camiseta_id Equals ca.camiseta_id _
            Where _
              ( _
                ((vc.disponivel_dtg = 0 And vc.qtd_estoque > 0) And vc.Camiseta.disponivel_dtg = 0) _
                Or _
                ( _
                    ((vc.disponivel_dtg = 0 And vc.qtd_estoque > 0) And vc.Camiseta.disponivel_dtg = 1) _
                    Or _
                    ((vc.disponivel_dtg = 1 And vc.qtd_estoque_canvas > 0) And vc.Camiseta.disponivel_dtg = 1) _
                ) _
              ) _
              And vc.ativo = 1 _
              And vc.Camiseta.ativo = 1 _
              And vc.Camiseta.ocultado_catalogo = 0 _
              And vc.preco > 0 _
              And IIf(genero = "i", vc.modelo_id = 3, vc.sexo = genero) _
            Select _
              id = vc.camiseta_id, _
              vid = vc.varcam_id, _
              r = vc.Camiseta.ranking_popularidade, _
              p = vc.preco - vc.desconto, _
              t = vc.tamanho.Replace("xxg", "ggg").Replace("xg", "gg"), _
              c = vc.cor_basica.ToLower(), _
              m = vc.modelo_id, _
              g = m.sexo, _
              d = vc.Camiseta.Design.DesignProducaoModelos.lancamento_id, _
              cm = m.value, _
              dl = ca.data_ultimo_lancamento _
            Order By dl Descending, id Descending
```

Comment: Is it possible that either vc.modelo, vc.sexo, or genero are null?

Comment: Also, are you getting an error when running this or does it just not return the right records?

Comment: No, genero always will have a value.

Comment: I don't think that `IIF` is doing what you think.  It does not short circuit.  Try using the new `IF` operator.